# Renaming/removing spaces in directories

Tags: linux, bash, directory, batch-rename, removing-whitespace

Pretty new to Linux, but have discovered the 'dislike' Linux have for spaces in names.

By using :`rename 's/ /_/g' *` it renames everything in that directory by adding a _underscore instead of the spaces.
So "**test dir nr 1** becomes "**test_dir_nr_1**" and "**test file 1.txt**" becomes "**test_file_1.txt**"

But! Is there anyway to make it automated and recursive (is that the right word?, ) doing subdirectories in subdirectories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `find`:

```
find . -name "* *" \( -type f -o -type d \) -execdir rename -v 's/ /_/g' {} +
```

This searches for regular files and directories containing a space character in their names using your current directory (`.`) as start directory and renames them recursively. I just added the `-v`erbose flag so you can see what happens.

To list the files and directories which would be affected by the command, remove the `-execdir` part:

```
find . -name "* *" \( -type f -o -type d \)
```

You can of course replace the `.` with an absolute or relative path.

Comment: Wow, that string was pretty impressive, it did it all, I expected a 10 page script ☺️ I'm still learning, so what does the last  {} +  do?

Comment: The `{}` is a placeholder and expands to the list of pathnames found by `find`, i.e. the `rename` command is executed on this list. The `+` is used to execute the command for as many matching pathnames as possible. There exists another variant with a semicolon `;` which would execute the command once for each file which results in multiple calls of the command and is slower. 
See [-execdir command {} +](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files) and [-execdir command ;](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Single-File).